# how to access variables declared in map outside it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two map functions and have assigned its data to variables, I want to compare them

```
!followerLoading && (
    followersData.map((e) => 
        {
            const myFollowers = e.requested_profile.Userlink
        }
    )
)

!followingLoading && (
followingData.map((e) => 
    {
        const myFollowings = e.requesting_profile.Userlink
    }
)
)

const btntext = myFollowers===myFollowings ? "Following" : "Follow"
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

Comment: [JavaScript is **not** Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping function will return an array as it iterates over. One way to tackle this problem is to compare the two arrays

```
const myFollowers = !followerLoading && (
    followersData.map((e) => e.requested_profile.Userlink )
)

const myFollowings = !followingLoading && (
followingData.map((e) => e.requesting_profile.Userlink)
)

const btntext = myFollowers.some(r=> myFollowings.includes(r))  ? "Following" : "Follow"
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-satoshi-yzh0i?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I tried this const myFollowers = !followerLoading && (
        followersData.map((e) => e.requested_profile.Userlink )
    )
    
    const myFollowings = !followingLoading && (
    followingData.map((e) => e.requesting_profile.Userlink)
    )

    const btntext = myFollowers.some(r=> myFollowings.includes(r))  ? "Following" : "Follow"    but every outcome is coming following, which is wrong

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-satoshi-yzh0i?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access variables outside of their scopes. So do the following:

Declare `myFollowers` and `myFollowings` outside the scope of .map() and initialize them with some values.

Then you can assign values to those variables from the .map() methods.

```js
let myFollowers = null;
let myFollowing = null;

followerLoading && (
    followersData.map((e) => 
        {
            myFollowers = e.requested_profile.Userlink
        }
    )
)
// Same for the other one

const btntext = myFollowers===myFollowings ? "Following" : "Follow";
```